# How to give permissions to project folder in Google Cloud to other user

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I have a project in Google Cloud Platform and I need to transfer it to another user. So far I gave owner rights to that user in IAM & Admin / Iam and he confirmed that he has access to the project, however when he goes to the Web Console Google Cloud Shell, he can not see the project folders and files.

But in my console, when I run the command ls, I can see the project folder.

How can he see the project folder in his web console, so he would edit and publish the changes?

I have tried to run the commands:
gsutil acl ch -u hisusername@gmail.com:O gs://project.appspot.com
gsutil acl ch -u hisusername@gmail.com:O gs://project.appspot.com

but he still does not have access to the project folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Cloud Shell isn't associated to a project. It's provisioned on a per-user, per-session basis. It is essentially a VM instances with [pre-installed tools](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/features#tools) to make it easier for a user to manage his projects and resources.

The other user will need to download the code on his Cloud Shell instance like he'd do on his local machine. For an App Engine Standard application, he can follow the doc [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/downloading-source-code). For an app in the flexible environment, he may refer to this [other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49444048/how-to-download-application-from-google-cloud-platform-java-flexible-environment/49445045#49445045).

Comment: Thanks! This seems to have fixed my problem. I ran the command *appcfg.py -A project-id -V 20180215 download_app output_folder* like in the second link you mentioned, and the files have now appeared for the other user.