# is there a way to export your app.yaml file from google cloud instance

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to create an instance with the same configuration and environment variables as my initial instance. How do I extract/export/download my app.yaml file from my google cloud instance? which folder is it stored in?

Answer (score 0):

One easy option is to go to the App Engine's [versions page](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions) in your Developer Console and click on the "view" link under config column for the service's version you want. A popup window will display the content of the app.yaml file.

Alternatively, you can download the app.yaml file along with all your app code. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49445045/4926605) to do so with App Engine Flexible or follow [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/downloading-source-code) for App Engine Standard environment.